issues when installing an existing DRF react app on pythonanywhere
What i need ?
Install and run given app code from link below on pythonanywhere
https://github.com/veryacademy/YT-Django-DRF-Simple-Blog-Series-JWT-Part-3.git
pre requisite is install npm, npx. For this I referred to page
https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/React/

what i am trying ?
CMIIAW. I presume that "react" folder in the git is already a create-react-app ( minus node_modules )
So to create node_modules folder I can create a new react app called "frontend" and copy node_modules into "react" folder
npm install -g react create-react-app
npx create-react-app frontend


what i am getting ?
(.myenv) 04:01 ~/YT-Django-DRF-Simple-Blog-Series-Part-1/react (master)$ npx create-react-app frontend --force

Creating a new React app in /home/nightly/YT-Django-DRF-Simple-Blog-Series-Part-1/react/frontend.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code Unknown system error -122
npm ERR! syscall write
npm ERR! errno -122
**npm ERR! Unknown system error -122: Unknown system error -122, write
**
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/nightly/.npm/_logs/2024-04-20T04_01_57_768Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting frontend/ from /home/nightly/YT-Django-DRF-Simple-Blog-Series-Part-1/react
Done.

Even a --force option does not help here.
How to solve this issue, so that I can run this code smoothly.
